# Django: Unable to load admin page and HTML page using TemplateView.as_view()

Tags: django

I used the [django-twoscoops](https://github.com/twoscoops/django-twoscoops-project) project template to setup a simple project (made some modifications to use django 2.2.5). My project urls.py looks like this:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path
from django.conf import settings
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

urlpatterns = [
    # Landing page.
    path('', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='base.html')),

    # Admin.
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),

    # Apps.
    path('polls/', include('apps.polls.urls')),
]
```

I ran check and no issues were found. When I run the server, and connect to *127.0.0.1:8000/admin/*
I get an error. However, if I go to *127.0.0.1:8000/polls/* the polls page loads OK. I also get an error if I try to go to *127.0.0.1:8000* (it complains base.html is not found and I don't understand why it is looking at a different path). I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Admin error:

```
OSError at /admin/login/

[Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'C:\\Users\\drpal\\PycharmProjects\\tvpv_portal\\:\\admin\\login.html'
```

Landing page error:

```
   Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Django Version: 2.2.5
Python Version: 3.7.5
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'apps.polls']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  145.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  143.                 response = response.render()

File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py" in render
  106.             self.content = self.rendered_content

File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py" in rendered_content
  81.         template = self.resolve_template(self.template_name)

File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py" in resolve_template
  63.             return select_template(template, using=self.using)

File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py" in select_template
  42.                 return engine.get_template(template_name)

File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py" in get_template
  34.             return Template(self.engine.get_template(template_name), self)

File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\engine.py" in get_template
  143.         template, origin = self.find_template(template_name)

File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\engine.py" in find_template
  125.                 template = loader.get_template(name, skip=skip)

File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\loaders\base.py" in get_template
  24.                 contents = self.get_contents(origin)

File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\loaders\filesystem.py" in get_contents
  23.             with open(origin.name, encoding=self.engine.file_charset) as fp:

Exception Type: OSError at /
Exception Value: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'C:\\Users\\drpal\\PycharmProjects\\tvpv_portal\\:\\base.html'
```

For landing page, I have set 'DIRS' in TEMPLATE dictionary to point to *C:\Users\drpal\PycharmProjects\tvpv_portal\templates* which contains base.html, so I'm not sure why it is looking one directory above.

The settings are shown below but I am not sure what the culprit could be:

```
ABSOLUTE_URL_OVERRIDES  

{}


ALLOWED_HOSTS   

[]

APPEND_SLASH    

True

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS     

['django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend']

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS    

'********************'

AUTH_USER_MODEL     

'auth.User'

CACHES  

{'default': {'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache'}}

CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_ALIAS  

'default'

CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_KEY_PREFIX     

'********************'

CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_SECONDS    

600

CSRF_COOKIE_AGE     

31449600

CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN  

None

CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY    

False

CSRF_COOKIE_NAME    

'csrftoken'

CSRF_COOKIE_PATH    

'/'

CSRF_COOKIE_SAMESITE    

'Lax'

CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE  

False

CSRF_FAILURE_VIEW   

'django.views.csrf.csrf_failure'

CSRF_HEADER_NAME    

'HTTP_X_CSRFTOKEN'

CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS    

[]

CSRF_USE_SESSIONS   

False

DATABASES   

{'default': {'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': False,
             'AUTOCOMMIT': True,
             'CONN_MAX_AGE': 0,
             'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
             'HOST': '',
             'NAME': 'C:\\Users\\drpal\\PycharmProjects\\tvpv_portal\\tvpv_portal\\dev_db.sqlite3',
             'OPTIONS': {},
             'PASSWORD': '********************',
             'PORT': '',
             'TEST': {'CHARSET': None,
                      'COLLATION': None,
                      'MIRROR': None,
                      'NAME': None},
             'TIME_ZONE': None,
             'USER': ''}}

DATABASE_ROUTERS    

[]

DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE     

2621440

DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_NUMBER_FIELDS   

1000

DATETIME_FORMAT     

'N j, Y, P'

DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS  

['%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
 '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f',
 '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M',
 '%Y-%m-%d',
 '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S',
 '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f',
 '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M',
 '%m/%d/%Y',
 '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S',
 '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S.%f',
 '%m/%d/%y %H:%M',
 '%m/%d/%y']

DATE_FORMAT     

'N j, Y'

DATE_INPUT_FORMATS  

['%Y-%m-%d',
 '%m/%d/%Y',
 '%m/%d/%y',
 '%b %d %Y',
 '%b %d, %Y',
 '%d %b %Y',
 '%d %b, %Y',
 '%B %d %Y',
 '%B %d, %Y',
 '%d %B %Y',
 '%d %B, %Y']

DEBUG   

True

DEBUG_PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS  

False

DECIMAL_SEPARATOR   

'.'

DEFAULT_CHARSET     

'utf-8'

DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE    

'text/html'

DEFAULT_EXCEPTION_REPORTER_FILTER   

'django.views.debug.SafeExceptionReporterFilter'

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE    

'django.core.files.storage.FileSystemStorage'

DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL  

'webmaster@localhost'

DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE    

''

DEFAULT_TABLESPACE  

''

DISALLOWED_USER_AGENTS  

[]

DJANGO_APPS     

['django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin']

DJANGO_ROOT     

'C:\\Users\\drpal\\PycharmProjects\\tvpv_portal\\tvpv_portal'

EMAIL_BACKEND   

'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'

EMAIL_HOST  

'localhost'

EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD     

'********************'

EMAIL_HOST_USER     

''

EMAIL_PORT  

25

EMAIL_SSL_CERTFILE  

None

EMAIL_SSL_KEYFILE   

'********************'

EMAIL_SUBJECT_PREFIX    

'[Django] '

EMAIL_TIMEOUT   

None

EMAIL_USE_LOCALTIME     

False

EMAIL_USE_SSL   

False

EMAIL_USE_TLS   

False

FILE_CHARSET    

'utf-8'

FILE_UPLOAD_DIRECTORY_PERMISSIONS   

None

FILE_UPLOAD_HANDLERS    

['django.core.files.uploadhandler.MemoryFileUploadHandler',
 'django.core.files.uploadhandler.TemporaryFileUploadHandler']

FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE     

2621440

FILE_UPLOAD_PERMISSIONS     

None

FILE_UPLOAD_TEMP_DIR    

None

FIRST_DAY_OF_WEEK   

0

FIXTURE_DIRS    

('C:\\Users\\drpal\\PycharmProjects\\tvpv_portal\\fixtures',)

FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME   

None

FORMAT_MODULE_PATH  

None

FORM_RENDERER   

'django.forms.renderers.DjangoTemplates'

IGNORABLE_404_URLS  

[]

INSTALLED_APPS  

['django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'apps.polls']

INTERNAL_IPS    

[]

LANGUAGES   

[('af', 'Afrikaans'),
 ('ar', 'Arabic'),
 ('ast', 'Asturian'),
 ('az', 'Azerbaijani'),
 ('bg', 'Bulgarian'),
 ('be', 'Belarusian'),
 ('bn', 'Bengali'),
 ('br', 'Breton'),
 ('bs', 'Bosnian'),
 ('ca', 'Catalan'),
 ('cs', 'Czech'),
 ('cy', 'Welsh'),
 ('da', 'Danish'),
 ('de', 'German'),
 ('dsb', 'Lower Sorbian'),
 ('el', 'Greek'),
 ('en', 'English'),
 ('en-au', 'Australian English'),
 ('en-gb', 'British English'),
 ('eo', 'Esperanto'),
 ('es', 'Spanish'),
 ('es-ar', 'Argentinian Spanish'),
 ('es-co', 'Colombian Spanish'),
 ('es-mx', 'Mexican Spanish'),
 ('es-ni', 'Nicaraguan Spanish'),
 ('es-ve', 'Venezuelan Spanish'),
 ('et', 'Estonian'),
 ('eu', 'Basque'),
 ('fa', 'Persian'),
 ('fi', 'Finnish'),
 ('fr', 'French'),
 ('fy', 'Frisian'),
 ('ga', 'Irish'),
 ('gd', 'Scottish Gaelic'),
 ('gl', 'Galician'),
 ('he', 'Hebrew'),
 ('hi', 'Hindi'),
 ('hr', 'Croatian'),
 ('hsb', 'Upper Sorbian'),
 ('hu', 'Hungarian'),
 ('hy', 'Armenian'),
 ('ia', 'Interlingua'),
 ('id', 'Indonesian'),
 ('io', 'Ido'),
 ('is', 'Icelandic'),
 ('it', 'Italian'),
 ('ja', 'Japanese'),
 ('ka', 'Georgian'),
 ('kab', 'Kabyle'),
 ('kk', 'Kazakh'),
 ('km', 'Khmer'),
 ('kn', 'Kannada'),
 ('ko', 'Korean'),
 ('lb', 'Luxembourgish'),
 ('lt', 'Lithuanian'),
 ('lv', 'Latvian'),
 ('mk', 'Macedonian'),
 ('ml', 'Malayalam'),
 ('mn', 'Mongolian'),
 ('mr', 'Marathi'),
 ('my', 'Burmese'),
 ('nb', 'Norwegian Bokmål'),
 ('ne', 'Nepali'),
 ('nl', 'Dutch'),
 ('nn', 'Norwegian Nynorsk'),
 ('os', 'Ossetic'),
 ('pa', 'Punjabi'),
 ('pl', 'Polish'),
 ('pt', 'Portuguese'),
 ('pt-br', 'Brazilian Portuguese'),
 ('ro', 'Romanian'),
 ('ru', 'Russian'),
 ('sk', 'Slovak'),
 ('sl', 'Slovenian'),
 ('sq', 'Albanian'),
 ('sr', 'Serbian'),
 ('sr-latn', 'Serbian Latin'),
 ('sv', 'Swedish'),
 ('sw', 'Swahili'),
 ('ta', 'Tamil'),
 ('te', 'Telugu'),
 ('th', 'Thai'),
 ('tr', 'Turkish'),
 ('tt', 'Tatar'),
 ('udm', 'Udmurt'),
 ('uk', 'Ukrainian'),
 ('ur', 'Urdu'),
 ('vi', 'Vietnamese'),
 ('zh-hans', 'Simplified Chinese'),
 ('zh-hant', 'Traditional Chinese')]

LANGUAGES_BIDI  

['he', 'ar', 'fa', 'ur']

LANGUAGE_CODE   

'en-us'

LANGUAGE_COOKIE_AGE     

None

LANGUAGE_COOKIE_DOMAIN  

None

LANGUAGE_COOKIE_NAME    

'django_language'

LANGUAGE_COOKIE_PATH    

'/'

LOCALE_PATHS    

[]

LOCAL_APPS  

['apps.polls']

LOGGING     

{'disable_existing_loggers': False,
 'filters': {'require_debug_false': {'()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'},
             'require_debug_true': {'()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugTrue'}},
 'formatters': {'simple': {'format': '{levelname} {message}', 'style': '{'},
                'verbose': {'format': '{levelname} {asctime} {module} '
                                      '{process:d} {thread:d} {message}',
                            'style': '{'}},
 'handlers': {'console': {'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
                          'filters': ['require_debug_true'],
                          'formatter': 'simple',
                          'level': 'INFO'},
              'mail_admins': {'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler',
                              'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
                              'formatter': 'simple',
                              'level': 'ERROR'}},
 'loggers': {'django': {'handlers': ['console'], 'propagate': True},
             'django.request': {'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
                                'level': 'ERROR',
                                'propagate': True}},
 'version': 1}

LOGGING_CONFIG  

'logging.config.dictConfig'

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL  

'/accounts/profile/'

LOGIN_URL   

'/accounts/login/'

LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL     

None



MEDIA_ROOT  

'C:\\Users\\drpal\\PycharmProjects\\tvpv_portal\\media'

MEDIA_URL   

'/media/'

MESSAGE_STORAGE     

'django.contrib.messages.storage.fallback.FallbackStorage'

MIDDLEWARE  

['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']

MIGRATION_MODULES   

{}

MONTH_DAY_FORMAT    

'F j'

NUMBER_GROUPING     

0

PASSWORD_HASHERS    

'********************'

PASSWORD_RESET_TIMEOUT_DAYS     

'********************'

PREPEND_WWW     

False

ROOT_URLCONF    

'tvpv_portal.urls'

SECRET_KEY  

'********************'

SECURE_BROWSER_XSS_FILTER   

False

SECURE_CONTENT_TYPE_NOSNIFF     

False

SECURE_HSTS_INCLUDE_SUBDOMAINS  

False

SECURE_HSTS_PRELOAD     

False

SECURE_HSTS_SECONDS     

0

SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER     

None

SECURE_REDIRECT_EXEMPT  

[]

SECURE_SSL_HOST     

None

SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT     

False

SERVER_EMAIL    

'root@localhost'

SESSION_CACHE_ALIAS     

'default'

SESSION_COOKIE_AGE  

1209600

SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN   

None

SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY     

True

SESSION_COOKIE_NAME     

'sessionid'

SESSION_COOKIE_PATH     

'/'

SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE     

'Lax'

SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE   

False

SESSION_ENGINE  

'django.contrib.sessions.backends.db'

SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE     

False

SESSION_FILE_PATH   

None

SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST  

False

SESSION_SERIALIZER  

'django.contrib.sessions.serializers.JSONSerializer'

SETTINGS_MODULE     

'tvpv_portal.settings.dev'

SHORT_DATETIME_FORMAT   

'm/d/Y P'

SHORT_DATE_FORMAT   

'm/d/Y'

SIGNING_BACKEND     

'django.core.signing.TimestampSigner'

SILENCED_SYSTEM_CHECKS  

[]

SITE_ID     

1

SITE_NAME   

'tvpv_portal'

SITE_ROOT   

'C:\\Users\\drpal\\PycharmProjects\\tvpv_portal'

STATICFILES_DIRS    

[]

STATICFILES_FINDERS     

['django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder']

STATICFILES_STORAGE     

'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.StaticFilesStorage'

STATIC_ROOT     

'C:\\Users\\drpal\\PycharmProjects\\tvpv_portal\\static'

STATIC_URL  

'/static/'

TEMPLATES   

[{'APP_DIRS': True,
  'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
  'DIRS': 'C:\\Users\\drpal\\PycharmProjects\\tvpv_portal\\templates',
  'OPTIONS': {'context_processors': ['django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                                     'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                                     'django.template.context_processors.i18n',
                                     'django.template.context_processors.media',
                                     'django.template.context_processors.static',
                                     'django.template.context_processors.request',
                                     'django.template.context_processors.tz',
                                     'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages'],
              'debug': True}}]

TEST_NON_SERIALIZED_APPS    

[]

TEST_RUNNER     

'django.test.runner.DiscoverRunner'

THOUSAND_SEPARATOR  

','

TIME_FORMAT     

'P'

TIME_INPUT_FORMATS  

['%H:%M:%S', '%H:%M:%S.%f', '%H:%M']

TIME_ZONE   

'America/Los_Angeles'

USE_I18N    

True

USE_L10N    

True

USE_THOUSAND_SEPARATOR  

False

USE_TZ  

True

USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST    

False

USE_X_FORWARDED_PORT    

False

WSGI_APPLICATION    

'tvpv_portal.wsgi.application'

X_FRAME_OPTIONS     

'SAMEORIGIN'

YEAR_MONTH_FORMAT   

'F Y'
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. Silly mistake. I was doing **DIRS = normpath(...)** in the TEMPLATES dictionary. Instead, it should be **DIRS = [ normpath(...) ]**. A **list** instead of a single value. Now it works.